# Drupal 7 Chain Batch Processes

Tags: drupal, batch-file, drupal-7

I have a series of functions that pass data to each other. I want to run these in sequence in batch so that each result would pass and array to the next function.

For example:

- Function 1 --> Processes files --> Outputs array
- Function 2 --> Inputs array --> Outputs array
- Function 3 --> Inputs array --> Creates nodes

I'm not explaining as well as I could but I'm unfamiliar with this process. Let me know if there is any additional information that you might need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the functions store results in $context['sandbox'] for the next function to process.  All batch functions in drupal should take a context parameter by reference as the last argument.  Note that this data should be session variable safe (no objects)